# Different preprocessing steps for time series data vs. regular cross sectional data?

Tags: time-series, data-preprocessing

What are the different preprocessing steps for time series data vs. regular cross sectional data?

- Eg 1. When doing train/test or cross validation, you cannot randomly split the data. The data must be split chronologically eg. train = year 2000-2005 data, test = 2006 data.
- Another one would be: 2. Make the dataset is stationary if it is nonstationary by differencing (model the difference between subsequent time-series values instead of the value itself). Removes the effect of trend or seasonality.
- What others am I missing?

Comment: Among the things you might be missing: mind the fact that differencing is not the appropriate technique to deal with trend or seasonality unless they produce a (nonseasonal or seasonal) unit root in the process.

Comment: So only do differencing if it produces a stationary time series?

Comment: Difference if there is a unit root.

Comment: Gotcha and to confirm unit root means: the line is nonstationary, but also does not have a trend.

Comment: It is more subtle than that. It may or may not have a trend (e.g. a random walk + a linear trend contains both a unit root and a trend). A unit root test might be helpful.